# How do you setup Eclipse to work on iPhone development (instead of Xcode)?

Tags: iphone, eclipse, macos

Although I've been getting more and more familiar with Xcode while developing for the iPhone, there are times I just wished I had a better IDE, something like Eclipse.

So I was wondering does anyone know how to migrate iPhone projects to Eclipse, and if it's worth it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XCode largely uses standard Unix tools for a lot of its work.  iPhone applications are compiled using GCC 4.0, it uses gdb for debugging, so it should be possible to set up Eclipse to at least compile applications.

If you look in the Build section of the Project Info pane (select the project, hit the Info button in XCode, choose the Build tab from the top) you can see many of the options.

I'm not sure what is required to copy a file to the simulator and attach a debugger to do a test run, it might not be worthwhile to jump through all the hoops and Apple may require an XCode generated build to accept an app into the App Store.

It may be the case that for regular code editing you can work reasonably well in Eclipse, then switch to XCode for interactive debugging.

Most of the existing Eclipse plugins seem to be oriented towards developer iPhone-aware web applications, so I'm not sure if you'll get any help there.

Comment: Xcode has some serious flaws, but one big reason to stick with it is code-signing. I don't believe that another IDE has the capability to sign your apps for testing on an actual device, or to sign an app for deployment to the App Store.

Code-signing may not matter for jailbroken devices, but if you intend to sell via the App Store, you'll need to make sure it happens.

Comment: I'd tolerate Xcode much better if it had far more keyboard shortcuts mapped and far more functional refactoring tools. Also, Xcode 8 seems really flimsy in terms of its pointing out errors. I basically have to try to run a program before it'll accurately reflect the current issues/warnings/errors. Eclipse has spoiled me.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you cant use Eclipse or any other IDE to develop for iPhone.
Apple only supports XCode and this wont change in the future. So I think you have to get used to XCode.

Answer (score 2):

Late in the game, but you might want to kick the tires with JetBrains's AppCode, eventually a full feature drop-in replacement for xCode ... and very similar to IntelliJ (GUI, work flows, etc...). Still Early Adopter as of now, it performs some tasks rather well. I still use xCode for configuring the build options and targeting the device, but that will eventually be taken care of.

regards

Answer (score 1):

There's cross compiling that give you ability to develop IPhone apps on eclipse
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TG-NIt2O5J8

Answer (score -2):

There are no plugins that support Apple IOS application development in Eclipse but on windows, you can develop using Adobe CS5. This is one of the powerful tool from Adobe in which you can develop .ipa applications on windows but you need some stuff to be ready before you start developing IOS applications using Adobe CS5