# Apple/iPhone Development IDE Preferences?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm going to do something I never thought I'd do...  learn how to program for Apple hardware .  After working in C, C++, C#, .NET, and even in the golden days of DOS (a little DOS4G/W memory extender in Borland Turbo-C, anyone?) and even as a kid, playing around with Atari 8-Bit Turbo-BASIC, I feel a little traitorous on multiple levels :)  Anyway, I'm going to grad school, studying music full-time - it'll be the first time in years I won't have a full-time programming gig - and I thought it would be fun to pick-up some Objective-C in my free-time - and maybe a little extra pocket change (one can always hope :)

So, **to the point of the post**.  I'm very used to Visual Studio, the designer, the XAML editor, the code-behind, blah blah blah.  A friend pulled up X-Code on his little MacBook to show off how cool it's supposed to be.  Sure, it has the same sorts of things as VS overall, but it seemed a little more scattered then I'd like.  I'm sure once I got used to it, it would be fine, but **I was just wondering if there are other good, free (or almost free)/or open-source editors out there for the Intel-based Apples that could also handle iPhone development.  Or any tips on getting into xCode?**  I've just decided to do this, so I feel like I'm starting from scratch.  I'm not slamming X-Code...  I haven't really used it yet.  I was just wondering what coders' preferences are.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It likes like XCode is the way to go.  Just takes some getting used to, just like anything else.  I did see Eclipse and Apanta (based off of Eclipse) as good alternatives, but those only handle Web-based apps, not native iPhone apps.  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207785/how-do-you-setup-eclipse-to-work-on-iphone-development-instead-of-xcode)

If Apple wants me to use XCode, and XCode is geared towards streamlined publication to the Apple Store, I'll be content.  Especially since it's free :) :)

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: The first thing I would do is switch it's windowing mode or get used to everything being scattered. I think there's a way for xcode to have a single pane.

Comment: Good comment...  that's the first thing that intimidates me with the XCode interface - all the scattered toolboxes.  I can live with it, but a single pane would be a little more gentle on my eyes.

Comment: Under the Xcode->Preferences menu item, you can change the Layout in the "General" pane from Default to All-in-one to decrease some of the 'scatter'. I think you'll find, however, that on a large monitor, Xcode does a pretty efficient job with its default layout once you get used to it. You can also open files in the project window's editor pane (use View->Zoom Editor In to show the editor pane if it's not visible when you *single* click on a source file in the Groups & Files pane. Double clicking will open a new editor window.

Comment: I consider myself somewhat of an Atari 8-bit guru. After all, I had the pleasure of editing Bill Wilkinson's Atari column in COMPUTE! Magazine. But I had to look up Turbo-Basic XL!

Comment: Ah, COMPUTE! Magazine.  My first forays into copying code :)  My dad and I would sit down in front of our old big TV with that blue screen and white square cursor and type in lines and lines of code to get the latest game saved onto our tape-drive.  For some reason, thinking of Apple reminds me of those competitive days and the 6502 wars :)

Thanks for the great comments and help, everyone!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There really is no alternative IDE on OS X for writing native applications. Some dislike the Xcode built-in editor, however. One very popular alternative is [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (non-free, but well worth the ~$50). Xcode can be configured to use your editor of choice for editing text files. Free alternatives include [Emacs](http://aquamacs.org/) and [Vim](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php) ports for OS X.

You can, of course, use the gcc toolchain without Xcode (e.g. using one of the Unix-style build systems such as Make). You can also use `xcodebuild` at the terminal command line to build an Xcode project without using the Xcode GUI at all (you'd be hard-pressed to configure and manage the project without the GUI, however). Combining these two, one could cobble together an IDE from e.g [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) to build an OS X app. iPhone would be harder since Xcode handles certificate signing etc. for you, but still possible. You would loose all of the nice Objective-C completion and documentation integration you get from Xcode, of course.

So, in summary, Xcode is pretty much the only game in town. It will undoubtedly take a while to get used to coming from VS. In particular, code generation is almost unheard of in the Cocoa world. When you feel yourself searching for those kind of tools, train yourself to try a different approach. Objective-C's late-binding combined with the power of NIB/XIB (bundles produced in Interface Builder that describe the UI of an app; XIB is a newer, version-control-friendly XML-based format that is automatically compiled into a NIB, the old-style format from NextStep days) makes code generation unnecessary.

For non-Cocoa/iPhone development, the ecosystem is naturally larger. Nokia has their own [IDE](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/developer-tools) for the Qt toolkit which can be used to write OS X (but not iPhone) apps. [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) can be used to write Java apps using any of the Java toolkits (including SWT and the Qt-Java framework, QtJambi).

For pure Windows-developer familiarity, there's also [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX) which runs on OS X. [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) may run on OS X, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I think XCode is the most popular choice amongst Cocoa developers. I think the best thing you could do is go straight into writing apps and exploring.

http://cocoadevcentral.com/ - Has some great tutorials, they're also usually very screenshot friendly.

Comment: Great link - lots of good info.  Thanks!  I'll start writing apps once I find a good little MacBook on Craigslist :)

Answer (score 1):

For pure ease XCode will be the way to go since it integrates with the iPhone simulator and Interface Builder.  Also, when you want to deploy your app to an actual device XCode does the certificate installation and management.  I don't have experience with any other IDE's for OSX though so I can't 100% answer your question. But, these are things you'll want to be aware of during your investigation.

Let us know what you find!