# Reference for iOS app design

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference

I want to learn objective C and adapt to xcode. I also want a reference with tutorials and examples to help me improve and become faster at ios app development. I am wasting too much time even for simple syntax errors. As there are several sources, I am quiet confused.

I have good C/C++ and C# background. I have significant UI design experience. I can also adapt well to open source libraries as I worked with opencv, opencvsharp, gtkmm, and qt for a long time. However, couldn't adapt to obj. C easily.

Where to start?

Comment: Google "Objective-C tutorial".

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this is about Xcode. They're two completely different things. First learn Objective-C (the language itself), write a couple of little programs, etc. using the normal command-line compiler, just like you would do that in case of any C or C++ project. Xcode as an IDE has quite a bit of a learning curve, and it will be only annoyance when you don't yet know the language. Dealing with **two** problems (learning Objective-C *and* trying to figure out what to do in Xcode) can be painful.

Comment: this isn't really a stackoverflow question i'm afraid however. You could start reading big nerd ranch for a better understanding of the syntax and it would be good if you would start building your own application to get the mind set for mobile development, there is no substitute for experience.

Comment: Googling doesn't work always if you want to find great refs like "O'Reilly- Learning Opencv" or "Aaron Hillegass- Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X". I was hoping for amazon links, author names, what the stackoverflow community did to learn this through..

Comment: I would definitely recommend that you get a couple of different real paper books on the topic.  I've got a couple from Apress and a couple from Wiley -- nothing specific to recommend since they're all several years old (pre-ARC, etc).  Online tutorials tend to be pretty weak, in my experience.

Comment: Watch Paul Hegarty's videos on iTunes U. I think a lot of us are learning it that way.

Comment: really confused about stackoverflow question requirements, whats the difference between my post and this one, should anyone explain please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983206/apple-iphone-development-ide-preferences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to learn is (since you have massive programming experience),

1. Play with XCode a while. Create a view based, tabbed, master-view application. See how xcode create the background code etc.
2. Learn Xcode - how Interface builder and storyboard works. How to link UI components with generated class files.

   2.1. Learn more about common UIComponents - UIView, Tabbar, TableView, SplitView etc.
3. Syntax of Objective c, message passing, property etc.

This tutorial is kinda popular and good,
http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Books: 
To start with UI concept, [Beginning iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430245123) is best to me.

Further you learn more about objective c in [Programming in objective c](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032188728X)

Apple tutorials on different topics,

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/