# Is it possible to do iPhone development in eclipse?

Tags: iphone, eclipse

Is it possible to do iPhone development in eclipse? If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you will find the answer here:

[How do you setup Eclipse to work on iPhone development (instead of Xcode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207785/how-do-you-setup-eclipse-to-work-on-iphone-development-instead-of-xcode)

Next time just query this site first before you post a question to save redundant posts