# Still not possible to use Eclipse instead of XCode for building an iOS app?

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode, macos, cordova

I'm developing a Phonegap/Cordova app for Android and iOS. For Android I use Eclipse on Windows. On Mac OS X you seem to be forced to use XCode, but since there's Eclipse on OS X too, I would like to use only that.

I found out that this was not possible in the past, but maybe it is these days.

Eclipse is a better editor than XCode in my opinion.
So my question is, is it even possible to develop, build and run for iOS in Eclipse ?   Or does *everybody* use XCode ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you setup Eclipse to work on iPhone development (instead of Xcode)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207785/how-do-you-setup-eclipse-to-work-on-iphone-development-instead-of-xcode)

Comment: If you think eclipse is a better editor than Xcode, then you can use eclipse for editting the source files of a project created with Xcode... Would that be enough? If not, then you will have to check how to compile an iOS project from the command line and use the ios-sim tool to try it on the simulator (you will need to install Xcode and its tools for sure anyway).

Comment: This author shows his own method using an Oracle instance: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/getting_started_with_ios_development , but I really think you should use XCode if you want native apps. There are other videos in that link which shows also Eclipse working with Objective-C and so on.

Comment: Everybody uses Xcode for iOS development.

Comment: Ok thank you.... I still find that hard to believe, though. As usual Apple thinks it knows better than me. I think OS X is the worst operating system available these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can't code, build and compile iOS app using eclipse. You need to use terminal/CMD to build your cordova project and XCode to compile and run into your simulator or actual device.

Answer (score 0):

Since cordova 3 was launched, you can use any editor you want, sublime, brackets, eclipse or any other.
You create the project with the cordova CLI and you work with the files on the root www folder.
You can use the CLI to run the app and generate the .ipa and .apk files, so you don't need xcode at all.

So answering your question, yes, you can use eclipse to create the app, but you have to use the CLI to run and install the app, eclipse doesn't have cordova CLI integration

Other IDEs like netbeans have eclipse integration, and editors like brackets have a cordova plugin to run the CLI from there